# Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite" Error with TupleUnion in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've been working with a TypeScript utility type, TupleUnion, which I came across in this [Twitter post](https://twitter.com/WrocTypeScript/status/1306296710407352321) and have seen used in multiple Stack Overflow solutions. The type is defined as follows:

```js
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
    [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U];
```

I tested this type using the TypeScript playground with the given [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhAqgOwJYHs0B4VQQAewEaAJgM5SXABOGaA5gDRQBKhJZVUAhmhABtALpQAvFFEA+CVADeAKACQQgMpRGUFCIBcUAKJEAxojjkI+NmtnFSFamggA3CHSgB+KQDpf7a2L68EiomDi4RqbmlijW0mxCvt7+UGoi0gDcigC+QjpZioykdABmfMbQAApulDgKilCNUCUYdLQAcnwAthD6tAzMWU1QiHwd3b009IxMQ03kWABG+gAifKRzjQAWYwDC65T6ZYiUEFnZioqgkFAA1hAg1JLByOjYePcgWCVQ1W04mSAA):

```
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    dob: Date;
    hasCats: false;
}
type keys = TupleUnion<keyof Person>;
```

This works as expected. However, when I slightly modify the Person interface by adding more properties:

```
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    dob: Date;
    hasCats: false;
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
    d: string;
    e: string;
    f: string;
}
```

I receive the following TypeScript error:

```
Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)
```

I'm curious why this utility type seems to work for others but results in an error in my case, especially when adding more properties to the interface. Is there a limit to the number of properties TupleUnion can handle, or is there something else I'm missing?

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's basically a combinatorics type, with the depth being a factorial of the number of members, so, yes, it only works with a small number of properties.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I think this is exactly the answer - the problem is the depth is factorial! If you would like to write this up as an answer I would be glad to accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The twitter post you link to says "Use with caution". This is why. It's not practical for real world.

`keyof` will create a list of each property: 'firstName' | 'a' | 'b' |.. etc.

Looking at the TupleUnion, for each entry in that `keyof`, it defines a subtype that is a tuple of all of the other entries, and this is recursive with a depth of the number of properties.

In other words, for each property, it recursively creates an entry for the object minus that 1 property, so 10 goes to 9 goes to 8, etc. The number of combinations and entries it needs is then 10 * 9 * 8...etc., which is `(properties.length)!`.  (factorial)

For 10 properties, that is 3,628,800 fields to define, and typescript stops you before you get that far.

With 4 properties, it is only 24. Pretty big difference.